# Ansible jinja2 merging lists to a single list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to iterate a list ["abc","def","ghi"] & each iteration generates a list which i need to set it to a variable in ansible.

here is my current script:

```
- name: add checks
  set_fact:
    CHECKS: "{% for cKey in checkKey %} {{ CHECKS|default([]) }} + {{ CHECKSMAP | map(attribute=cKey ) | list |join(',')}} {% endfor %}"
```

which generates the following output which is a string & not a list how can i append to the single list similar to list += temp_list in a for loop

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
"msg": "System  [] + [{u'check': u'system_checks'}, {u'check': u'lms_server_health'}]  [] + [{u'check': u'system_checks'}, {u'check': u'config-service_server_health'}, {u'check': u'config-service_server_restart'}] "   }
```

Comment: I coudn't find a question mark in your question. What's your question is?

Answer (score 2):

> which generates the following output which is a string & not a list

It's a string for two reasons: first off, you embedded a `" + "` bit of text in the middle of your expression, and the second is because you called `join(',')` and jinja cheerfully did as you asked.

> how can i append to the single list similar to list += temp_list in a for loop

The answer is to do exactly as you said and use an intermediate variable:

```
CHECKS: >-
  {%- set tmp = CHECKS | default([]) -%}
  {%- for cKey in checkKey -%}
  {%-   set _ = tmp.extend(CHECKSMAP | map(attribute=cKey ) | list) -%}
  {%- endfor -%}
  {{ tmp }}
```

[AFAIK](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#assignments), you have to use that `.extend` trick because a `set tmp = tmp +` will declare a new `tmp` inside the loop, rather than assigning the `tmp` outside the loop

Comment: This does not output a single list

Comment: (a) without including what it **did** output, I don't believe you (b) if `tmp` isn't a list that's because your initial `CHECKS` isn't a list, so you'll have to adjust accordingly

Comment: I think I looked all around the web to find this great answer !